# for loop in VS Code / python does not start

Tags: python, for-loop, visual-studio-code

I am working with Python 3.7 in VS Code.

Since an hour it seems like I cannot start for loops anymore. for example if I try

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
```

In my Terminal the following shows up:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...         print(i)
...
```

It changes only if i run a different line of code, then it gives me an error message. For me it looks like VS Code is waiting for further input in the loop.
for example if I interrupt it with

```
a = 1
```

and run that twice, it looks like:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...         print(i)
... a = 1
File "<stdin>", line 1
a = 1
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> a = 1
```

when working in jupyter notebook for example, everything works fine, so I guess it has sth to do with VS Code.

Comment: When your using an interactive Python session, leave a blank line (just press return an extra time) after a multi-line command, to signal that the indented block is finished.

Answer (score 4):

Press Enter after the loop is finished. Leave the final line blank and hit enter again. The loop should work fine.